# Windows Phone Universal App Hide Hub Section or create dynamically

Tags: windows, windows-phone, universal

I wan to hide one Hub section sometimes or i want to create id dynamically so i can decide what will be shown

```
 <HubSection HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HubItemHeader}" 
                        Header="{Binding MyViewModel}" 
                        DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}" 
                        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyList}" 
                        Visibility="{Binding IsDisplayed, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" />
```

i tried this but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamic add Hub Section in C#

```
HubSection hubSection= new HubSection();

this.Hub.Sections.Add(theHubSection);
```

read this:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c9b4355-59de-4a5a-bf7d-3459a2ee760d/adding-hubsections-dynamically?forum=w81prevwCsharp